# Error in using glob function with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

is the following ... To trying to retrieve images from a folder eat the native php function glob, only that is returning an empty array ... and I'm passing the full path to the folder function ...

```
$pasta = get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/projetos/' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'projeto', true) .'/';              

$imagens = glob("$pasta{*jpg,*png}", GLOB_BRACE) or die ("Erro ao acessar $pasta");
```

Answer (score 1):

You missing to `*` any of image file, You are passing full path of folder but you missing to which are file you want to take thats why use `*` all `jpg` and `png` extension file, Try this way,

```
$pasta = get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/projetos/' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'projeto', true) .'/';              

$imagens = glob("$pasta . "*. {jpg,png}", GLOB_BRACE) or die ("Erro ao acessar $pasta");
```